# MYSQL Concat() syntax error?

Tags: mysql

I want to add concatenated value to the params variable in mysql procedure. But mysql says it has a syntax error. What is the syntax error I'm doing here?

```
SET parms =CONCAT('s','sa');

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop = TRUE;
```

Mysql complains that the error is in 2nd line. But I think I'm doing something wrong in 1st line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you put `DECLARE` in the wrong place.

> **[DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare.html)**
>   DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement
>   and must be at **its start, before any other statements**.

More over the declarations must follow a specific order:

1. variables and conditions
2. cursors
3. handlers

That being said, this will do just fine

```sql
DECLARE parms VARCHAR(32);
DECLARE exit_loop INT;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop = TRUE;

SET parms = CONCAT('s','sa');
```

Let's try it:

```
mysql> DELIMITER //
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE myproc()
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE parms VARCHAR(32);
    ->   DECLARE exit_loop INT;
    ->   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop = TRUE;
    -> 
    ->   SET parms = CONCAT('s','sa');
    ->   SELECT parms;
    -> END
    -> //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql> CALL myproc();
+-------+
| parms |
+-------+
| ssa   |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```